# How to set DPI in cairographics?

Tags: pdf-generation, vector-graphics, cairo

When creating vector graphics for PDFs, I use one of the "create" functions for PDF rendering, for instance `cairo_pdf_surface_create_for_stream`. The signature of that function is:

```
cairo_surface_t *   cairo_pdf_surface_create_for_stream (cairo_write_func_t write_func,
                                                         void *closure,
                                                         double width_in_points,
                                                         double height_in_points);
```

Now, I can set the size of the surface in points, but the size of one point is seemingly hardcoded. in the description it says:

> width_in_points: width of the surface, in points (1 point == 1/72.0 inch)
>   height_in_points: height of the surface, in points (1 point == 1/72.0 inch)

As you can see, 1pt = 1/72" (72 dpi). But how do I change that setting?

I could factor something into the size, when using a different resolution and compensate that way, but this seems to me like worst practice ever.

Answer (score 3):

[A point is a standard typograpical unit of measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#Current_DTP_point_system). Whether or not you're talking about Cairo, a point is simply 1/72". It's not some setting you change, just like the fact that you don't change the number of inches in a foot.

The whole reason for using a *physical* measurement (points) instead of a *screen-dependent* one (pixels) is resolution-independence. This is a Good Thing.

What are you hoping to accomplish by changing the DPI?

Comment: The point is, I need by specification the ability to set the  resolution in dpi. When creating PDFs, you can set the dpi parameter in things like Inkscape, etc. (resolution for rasterization).

Comment: But PDFs are not rasterized and thus have no such resolution! However, if you do drawing which cairo cannot express in PDFs, it will use the fallback resolution which you can set with cairo_surface_set_fallback_resolution (see answer from john358). So what exactly do you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

If by "change the dpi" you want to draw at a different scale than 1/72" you can use cairo_scale(). If you are referring to the dpi of fallback images (regions that are rasterized becasue they can not be drawn natively by pdf) use cairo_surface_set_fallback_resolution().

Comment: Hi! I am trying to create a PDF with larger dimenstions, and then downscale to A4 paper using scale api for printing.But I am unable to update the cairo PDF paper size with scale API. Any ideas, plz?